# How to change the output file name from part-00000 in reducer to inputfile name

Tags: java, hadoop2

Currently I am able to implement the name change from `part-00000` to a custom fileName in mapper. I am doing this by taking the `inputSplit`. I tried the same in reducer to rename the file but, fileSplit method is not available for reducer. So, is there a best way to rename the output of a reducer to with inputfile name. Below is how I acheived it in mapper.

```
@Override
    public void setup(Context con) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        fileName = ((FileSplit) con.getInputSplit()).getPath().getName();
        fileName = fileName.substring(0,36);
        outputName = new Text(fileName);  

        final Path baseOutputPath = FileOutputFormat.getOutputPath(con);
        final Path outputFilePath = new Path(baseOutputPath, fileName);
        TextOutputFormat<IntWritable, Text> write = new TextOutputFormat<IntWritable, Text>() {
        @Override
        public Path getDefaultWorkFile(TaskAttemptContext context, String extension) throws IOException {
        return outputFilePath;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what hadoop [wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/FAQ#How_do_I_change_final_output_file_name_with_the_desired_name_rather_than_in_partitions_like_part-00000.2C_part-00001.3F) says:

```
You can subclass the OutputFormat.java class and write your own. You can locate and browse the code of TextOutputFormat, MultipleOutputFormat.java, etc. for reference. It might be the case that you only need to do minor changes to any of the existing Output Format classes. To do that you can just subclass that class and override the methods you need to change.
```

If you need to be on key and input file format, then you could create subclass of [MultipleOutputFormat](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/MultipleOutputFormat.html) to control output file name.

Comment: I tried this. Using this way, I could edit my part-00000 file name but how could I obtain inputfile name as my reducer output name. I have been able to getinputsplit name and used it in mapper. Similarly is there a way to read the split in reducer.

Comment: One way i could think of is to set parameter in configuration in driver code and use Context.getConfiguration to get the value.

Comment: But this process wont help if there are more than 1 file in a folder.

Comment: @Zzz were you able to remove r-00000 extention also .If yes can you please look at my question .I am also facing same issue here . [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42547065/how-to-remove-r-00000-extention-from-reducer-output-in-mapreduce?noredirect=1#comment72229835_42547065)

Comment: @SUDARSHAN. i was able to modify the file name but failed to remove the part-00000.

Comment: @Zzz finally i modified it explicitly after job completion .and its working just fine for me now without any delay ,I have added code my answer also .Thanks