# How to remove r-00000 extention from reducer output in mapreduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

I am able to rename my reducer output file correctly but r-00000 is still persisting .
I have used MultipleOutputs in my reducer class .
Here is details of the that .Not sure what am i missing or what extra i have to do?

```
public class MyReducer extends Reducer<NullWritable, Text, NullWritable, Text> {

    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyReducer.class);
    private MultipleOutputs<NullWritable, Text> multipleOutputs;
    String strName = "";
    public void setup(Context context) {
        logger.info("Inside Reducer.");
        multipleOutputs = new MultipleOutputs<NullWritable, Text>(context);
    }
    @Override
    public void reduce(NullWritable Key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        for (Text value : values) {
            final String valueStr = value.toString();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(strArrvalueStr[0] + "|!|");
            multipleOutputs.write(NullWritable.get(), new Text(sb.toString()),strName);
        }
    }

    public void cleanup(Context context) throws IOException,
            InterruptedException {
        multipleOutputs.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this question is duplicate please see the following link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27488624/how-to-change-the-output-file-name-from-part-00000-in-reducer-to-inputfile-name

Comment: I have overriden generateFileName() method but could not be able to remove r-0000 extension.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do it explicitly after my job finishes and thats ok for me.No delay in the job

```
if (b){
            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HHmm");
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            String strDate=dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
            FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(getConf());
            FileStatus fs[] = hdfs.listStatus(new Path(args[1]));
            if (fs != null){ 
                for (FileStatus aFile : fs) {
                    if (!aFile.isDir()) {
                        hdfs.rename(aFile.getPath(), new Path(aFile.getPath().toString()+".txt"));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: How to do the same in spark output ?

Answer (score 1):

A more suitable approach to the problem would be changing the OutputFormat.

For eg :- If you are using TextOutputFormatClass, just get the source code of the TextOutputFormat class and modify the below method to get the proper filename (without r-00000). We need to then set the modified output format in the driver.

```
public synchronized static String getUniqueFile(TaskAttemptContext context, String name, String extension) {
    /*TaskID taskId = context.getTaskAttemptID().getTaskID();
    int partition = taskId.getId();*/
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    result.append(name);        
    /*
     * result.append('-');
     * result.append(TaskID.getRepresentingCharacter(taskId.getTaskType()));
     * result.append('-'); result.append(NUMBER_FORMAT.format(partition));
     * result.append(extension);
     */
    return result.toString();
}
```

So whatever name is passed through the multiple outputs, filename will be created according to it.